# iOS Drawer and Header Image within SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

Ho can I add header image to [SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/blob/master/README.md) menu in iOS?

For example like material drawer have it for Android:

[image]

Can I modify somehow that UI Table View controller to put some custom UI above the menu rows or any other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a seperate `UIViewController`.
2. Add your custom views and a tableView to it.
3. Make the Delegate and Datasource for the tableView your viewController class.

Also i'd recommend making an `IBOutlet` for your tableView so it acts just like a `UITableViewController` (which behind the scenes is a just a normal `UIViewController` with its view being a UITableView and the delegate and datasource for the tableView being the view controller itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely modify. Use any `viewcontroller` in place of `tableviewcontroller`.You will be able to add anything on it's view and do whatever you want. Good luck.